# Select programmatically front first button to last button

Tags: c#

I am finishing software for disabled people with muscular dystrophy.

How to programmatically select the first button, after second select second button, after second next button. This select first button to last button in the loop with the second delay.

I am a beginner in c#, please for working examples.

I tried below code:

```
Count++;
Cursor.point = pointtoscreen(button[Count]);
```

The above code is not working.

Comment: Does `pointtoscreen` do anything if you call it like this `pointtoscreen(0);`?  If not, you need to get that working *expressly* before we can get it working *procedurally*

Comment: I am beginner, can't create working code. I am need examples

Answer (score 0):

To do anything repeatedly with some time between you would use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

To select a button, or any other control you would call '[focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)' to 'select' it.

To move focus between different controls you would need some kind of list to iterate over, but there is also a [tabIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-tab-order?view=netdesktop-6.0) that may be used to provide a order for all controls.

So create a timer and an index. When the timer elapses you increment the index, find the control with the corresponding tabIndex, and focus it. You might also need some logic to wrap around to zero index. An alternative would be to [simulate pressing the tab-key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/how-to-simulate-events?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Comment: Thx, you solution is beter, like main solution